Ubuntu server not showing free space tab
I tried to install Ubuntu Server on my laptop to dual boot with Windows 11. Everything went great until the part of storage configuration. I can see the local drive with the Windows partitions, but I can't see the free space tab to create the new partitions for Ubuntu server.
as you can see in the image the local drive is 1TB, and I have more than 300GB of free space to install Ubuntu Server.


I don't remember off the top of my head but what happens if you hit the right arrow key with the drive selected? Does it allow you
